# Apache httpd LDAP integration

Tags: apache-2.2, svn, ldap, httpd, httpd.conf

I am configuring a CollabNet Subversion integration. I have the following `collabnet_subversion.conf` file:

```
<Location /svn>
  DAV svn
  SVNParentPath /mnt/svn/new_repos
  SVNListParentPath on
  AuthName "VegiBanc Source Repository"
  AuthType basic
  AuthzLDAPAuthoritative off
  AuthBasicProvider ldap
  AuthLDAPURL ldap://ldap.vegibanc.com/dc=vegibanc,dc=com?sAMAccountName" NONE
  AuthLDAPBindDN "CN=SVN-Admin,OU=Service Accounts,OU=VegiBanc Users,OU=vegibanc,DC=vegibanc,DC=com"
  AuthLDAPBindPassword "swordfish"
</Location>
```

This works great. Any user in our Active Directory can access our Subversion repository.

Now, I want to limit this to only people in the Active Directory group *Development*:

```
<Location /svn>
  DAV svn
  SVNParentPath /mnt/svn/new_repos
  SVNListParentPath on
  AuthName "VegiBanc Source Repository"
  AuthType basic
  AuthzLDAPAuthoritative off
  AuthBasicProvider ldap
  AuthLDAPURL ldap://ldap.vegibanc.com/dc=vegibanc,dc=com?sAMAccountName" NONE
  AuthLDAPBindDN "CN=SVN-Admin,OU=Service Accounts,OU=VegiBanc Users,OU=VegiBanc,DC=vegibanc,DC=com"
  AuthLDAPBindPassword "swordfish"
  Require ldap-group CN=Development, OU=Security Groups, OU=VegiBanc, dc=vegibanc, dc=com
</Location>
```

I added `Require ldap-group`, but now no one can log in. I have `LogLevel` set to `debug`, but all I get is this in my `error_log` (Single line broken up for easier reading):

```
[Thu Oct 11 13:09:28 2012] [info] [client 10.55.9.45] [6752] 
    vauth_ldap authenticate: user dweintraub authentication failed;
    URI /svn/ [ldap_search_ext_s() for user failed][Bad search filter]
```

And, I get this in my `access_log`:

```
10.55.9.45 - - [11/Oct/2012:13:09:27 -0500] "GET /svn/ HTTP/1.1" 401 401
10.55.9.45 - dweintraub [11/Oct/2012:13:09:28 -0500] "GET /svn/ HTTP/1.1" 500 535
```

Yes, I am in that group. (Or, at least how can I confirm that just to make sure that's not the issue. I have the SysinternalsSuite ADExplorer. It's where I'm getting all of my info.)

Comment: Looks similar but there is no "Bad search filter" on the error log: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3178051/problem-authenticating-user-for-subversion-using-apache-and-ldap

did you try any steps from there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not specify the group's DN correctly, and you can see by the error message. It should probably look like this:

```
Require ldap-group CN=Development,OU=Security Groups,OU=VegiBanc,dc=vegibanc,dc=com
```

**Edit**: Since this doesn't seem to be the problem, make sure you have

```
AuthLDAPGroupAttribute member uniquemember
AuthLDAPGroupAttributeIsDN on
```

set, which I assume is correct for your AD environment. These are the defaults in `mod_authnz_ldap` but it can only help to set them explicitly.

I don't really have any other ideas, your configuration looks correct. I am only wondering why you had no `Require` directive in your original configuration. But you said it was working so maybe it defaults to `Require valid-user`.

**Edit 2:** Since we are running a quite similar setup (but not with AD), I reviewed our configuration and found that one can't use `Require ldap-group` along with Subversion's authorization features. This is documented here: https://ctf.open.collab.net/sf/go/artf4917. In our case this was a non-issue since we use `AuthzSVNAccessFile` for authorization. The `Require ldap-group` seems to have simply behaved like `Require valid-user`.

This doesn't really explain to me why you get a "Bad search filter" message, but in order to only allow members of your Development group to access the `/svn` location you should extend the `AuthLDAPURL` with a group filter and remove the `Require ldap-group` directive. Since you are using AD you can use `memberOf` along these lines:

```
AuthLDAPURL ldap://ldap.vegibanc.com/dc=vegibanc,dc=com?sAMAccountName?sub?(&(objectCategory=person)(memberOf=CN=Development,OU=Security Groups,OU=VegiBanc,dc=vegibanc,dc=com)) NONE
```

More detail here:

http://subversion.open.collab.net/ds/viewMessage.do?dsForumId=3&dsMessageId=417401

https://ctf.open.collab.net/sf/wiki/do/viewPage/projects.svnedge/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#section-FrequentlyAskedQuestions-HowCanIRestrictLogonToMembersOfAParticularGroup

Comment: Sorry, missed two commas in the `Require ldap-group`. I had to edit what I was doing in order to hide proprietary information. (Hint: Password isn't really _swordfish_). However, the official [Apache documentation for Require ldap-group](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authnz_ldap.html#reqgroup) specifically states "_Do not surround the group name with quotes_". I copied the LDAP group directly from ADExplorer, so I know it's correct.

Comment: Right, sorry about the quotes. I'll update my answer with something else you could try.

Comment: Thanks. It looks like this is an issue with CollabNet's Subversion package. Previously, I've either used the native package or rolled my own. It looks like the way they've compiled Apache, it forces to use SVN's authz. I'll try the filter to see if it works.

Comment: Okay, I found ***a*** [solution](http://serverfault.com/a/437767/117826). It's not what you recommended, but your explanation and links lead me to this solution. I tried the filtering, but it didn't seem to work. Probably because I didn't have the `Require valid-user` line.

Answer (score 2):

I'm giving this to [daff](https://serverfault.com/a/437490/117826) anyway because his links lead me to the actual issue. I couldn't get the filtering to work like daff suggested, but I did find the problem.

The statement that lead me to the solution was:

> Since we are running a quite similar setup (but not with AD), I reviewed our configuration and found that one can't use Require ldap-group along with Subversion's authorization features.

Several links *daff* suggested commented on this and offered no solution except to use filtering which I couldn't seem to get to work.

I then decided to look at `http.conf` which Collabnet provided. And here's what I saw:

```
#LoadModule python_module      opt/CollabNet_Subversion/modules/mod_python.so
LoadModule dav_svn_module     opt/CollabNet_Subversion/modules/mod_dav_svn.so
LoadModule authz_svn_module   opt/CollabNet_Subversion/modules/mod_authz_svn.so
#LoadModule dontdothat_module  opt/CollabNet_Subversion/modules/mod_dontdothat.so
```

Ah! They're loading `authz_svn_module`! I simply disabled it:

```
#LoadModule python_module      opt/CollabNet_Subversion/modules/mod_python.so
LoadModule dav_svn_module     opt/CollabNet_Subversion/modules/mod_dav_svn.so
#LoadModule authz_svn_module   opt/CollabNet_Subversion/modules/mod_authz_svn.so
#LoadModule dontdothat_module  opt/CollabNet_Subversion/modules/mod_dontdothat.so
```

And then went back to my ___original____ configuration in `collabnet_subversion.conf`:

```
<Location /svn>
  DAV svn
  SVNParentPath /mnt/svn/new_repos
  SVNListParentPath on
  AuthName "VegiBanc Source Repository"
  AuthType basic
  AuthzLDAPAuthoritative off
  AuthBasicProvider ldap
  AuthLDAPURL ldap://ldap.vegibanc.com/dc=vegibanc,dc=com?sAMAccountName" NONE
  AuthLDAPBindDN "CN=SVN-Admin,OU=Service Accounts,OU=VegiBanc Users,OU=VegiBanc,DC=vegibanc,DC=com"
  AuthLDAPBindPassword "swordfish"
  Require ldap-group CN=Development, OU=Security Groups, OU=VegiBanc, dc=vegibanc, dc=com
</Location>
```

And, it now worked like a charm!

Thanks daff for your help. I think my issue with the filter is that I needed `Require valid-user` and I hadn't put that in, but this does now work.