# SVN Authentication using Active Directory

Tags: apache-2.2, active-directory, svn

Is it possible to use Active Directory (Server 2008 R2) to manage users for a subversion repo that's hosted on Debian (Wheezy)?

I've tried linking the SVN hosted on Apache on a Debian server to the Active Directory on the windows server. I'm able to check out the repository however when I go to commit my changes I get a commit failed authorization failed (using tortoisesvn on a windows client, it never even asks for credentials when committing)

I'm using apache2 | 2.2.22-13+deb7u1

dav_svn.conf below:

```
<Location /svn>
DAV svn
SVNParentPath /srv/repos/svn
SVNListParentPath on
AuthName "helloworld"
AuthType basic
AuthzLDAPAuthoritative off
AuthBasicProvider ldap
AuthLDAPURL ldap://192.168.1.10/dc=example,dc=com?sAMAccountName" NONE
AuthLDAPBindDN "CN=subversion,OU=Users,DC=example,DC=com"
AuthLDAPBindPassword "secret"
Require ldap-group CN=svn,OU=groups,dc=example,dc=com
</Location>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to specify the global catalog port in the AuthLDAPURL.  I got it to work using the config below:

```
<Location /svn>
    DAV svn
    AuthType basic
    SVNParentPath /srv/repos/svn
    AuthName "helloworld"
    AuthBasicProvider ldap
    AuthLDAPURL "ldap://192.168.1.10:3268/dc=example,dc=com?sAMAccountName" NONE
    AuthLDAPBindDN "CN=subversion,CN=users,DC=example,DC=com"
    AuthLDAPBindPassword "secret"
    Require ldap-group CN=svn,OU=groups,DC=example,DC=com
</Location>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your config is **just terrible bad** (I can see a *few* correct string). Use config from [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/437434/apache-httpd-ldap-integration) as good starting point (it miss only `Require valid-user` from my POV)